# Can TreeView nodes have intermediate checked states?

Tags: c#, treeview

Here is what I am looking to do:

- Represent a set of options, divided by category.
- Allow the user to check/uncheck all items within a category by checking/unchecking the category node.
- Show that some options within a category are checked by setting the category node to an intermediate checked state.

From what I've read, and my limited experience with TreeViews, this last desirable doesn't appear possible, as TreeNodes don't seem to support anything other than a on/off checked state.  Is this possible using a TreeView?  Is there some other control that could pull this off, or am I going to have to make a sub-class of TreeView to get it done?

Comment: Hi, handling 'indeterminate checkbox states in a TreeView (without wading into the "swamp" of sub-classing the WinForms native TreeView which is a wrapper around a "fossil," and really difficult to sub-class and create an owner-drawn version with custom "painting") is one reasons why I use a 3rd. party TreeView which has the features you are describing built-in. You can view my comments on the one I use on this post on SO : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1983600/c-treeview-check-number-of-checked-children/1983715#1983715

Answer (score 3):

You could use a custom `TreeView` supporting three states `checkBoxes`, such as [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tree/Tri-State_Tree_View.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It can be done by using the DrawMode property so you can paint your own check box with ControlPaint.DrawCheckBox().  You'll also have to implement the MouseDown event and use the HitTest method to detect clicks on the fake checkbox.  No great joy, but it's possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is my solution form Windows Vista and higher:

```
Public Structure TV_ITEM
    Public mask As UInteger
    Public hItem As IntPtr
    Public state As UInteger
    Public stateMask As UInteger
    <Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalAs(Runtime.InteropServices.UnmanagedType.LPTStr)>
    Public pszText As String
    Public cchTextMax As Integer
    Public iImage As Integer
    Public iSelectedImage As Integer
    Public cChildren As Integer
    Public lParam As IntPtr
End Structure

Public Class TreeViewEx
    Inherits TreeView
    Private Const TVIF_HANDLE As UInteger = &H10
    Private Const TVIF_STATE As UInteger = &H8
    Private Const TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK As UInteger = &HF000
    Private Const TV_FIRST As UInteger = &H1100
    Private Const TVM_SETITEM As UInteger = TV_FIRST + 13
    Private Const TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE As UInteger = TV_FIRST + 44
    Private Const TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER As UInteger = &H4
    Private Const TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES As UInteger = &H80

    Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As TV_ITEM) As IntPtr
    Private Declare Auto Function SendMessage Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByRef lParam As IntPtr) As IntPtr

    Private Function INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(i As Integer) As Integer
        Return i << 12
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Sub OnHandleCreated(e As System.EventArgs)
        Dim style As UInteger = TVS_EX_DOUBLEBUFFER Or TVS_EX_PARTIALCHECKBOXES
        SendMessage(Me.Handle, TVM_SETEXTENDEDSTYLE, New IntPtr(style), New IntPtr(style))
        MyBase.OnHandleCreated(e)
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetNodeCheckState(node As TreeNode, state As CheckState)
        If state = CheckState.Indeterminate Then
            If System.Environment.OSVersion.Version.Major >= 6 Then
                Dim it As TV_ITEM = Nothing
                it.mask = TVIF_HANDLE Or TVIF_STATE
                it.hItem = node.Handle
                it.stateMask = TVIS_STATEIMAGEMASK
                it.state = INDEXTOSTATEIMAGEMASK(3) 'indeterminate
                SendMessage(Me.Handle, TVM_SETITEM, IntPtr.Zero, it)
            Else
                node.Checked = False
            End If
        Else
            node.Checked = (state = CheckState.Checked)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write that feature yourself.  You could keep it simple and just colour the checkbox a light gray or something to show an intermediate state.

If you're using WPF, I think you might be able to alter the control template of the treeview and/or the control template of the checkbox.

In WPF I would say it would be easier to implement then winforms. Not sure what technology you're using in this case.