# how to change to check box on a TreeView control to "Indetermined" state?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the following Treeview with the check boxes

[image]

As you can see GEAR is the root node of several gears nodes. what I want to do is when i uncheck a gear node the root node GEAR must be set to indetermined, How do i do that?
thanks

Comment: [Related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010288/can-treeview-nodes-have-intermediate-checked-states).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that as far as I know using the standard treeview, but you can do owner drawn style.

1. set DrawMode property to OwnerDrawAll
2. then using DrawNode event, add your code to draw anything you want

or to assign an ImageList in the TreeView,and change the image index according to the state of the tree node. Here is a sample (*though it is written in VB but it can give a lot of hints*):
[Sample here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/controls/treeview/misc-advanced/article.php/c3983/TreeView-with-ThreeState-Checkboxes.htm)